Does list of records need the same key?
I have defined the following interfaces:
export interface userInfo {
    bio: {
        name: string;
    },
    responses: Record<string, Response>;
}

export interface Response {
    answer: string;
    level: number;
}

export interface userInformation {
    information: userInfo[];
}


But when I'm trying to get following mock data, I'm getting an error.

    mockUserInfo() {
        return [
            {
                information: [
                    {
                        bio: {
                            name: 'john',
                        },
                        responses: {
                            favoriteColor: {
                                answer: 'green',
                                level: 5
                            },
                            favoriteFood: {
                                answer: 'pasta',
                                level: 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        bio: {
                            name: 'jane',
                        },
                        responses: {
                            favoriteColor: {
                                answer: 'white',
                                level: 5
                            },
                            favoriteFood: {
                                answer: 'Fish',
                                level: 5
                            },
                            favoriteCar: {
                                answer: 'Ford',
                                level: 5
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }


    getUserInfo(): Observable<userInformation[]> {
        return new Observable((subscriber) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                subscriber.next(this.mockUserInfo());
                subscriber.complete();
            }, 100);
        });
    }


The error is:
Argument of type '{ information: ({ bio: { name: string; }; responses: { favoriteColor: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteFood: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteCar?: undefined; }; } | { bio: { name: string; }; responses: { ...; }; })[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'userInformation[]'.
  Type '{ information: ({ bio: { name: string; }; responses: { favoriteColor: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteFood: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteCar?: undefined; }; } | { bio: { name: string; }; responses: { ...; }; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'userInformation'.
    Types of property 'information' are incompatible.
      Type '({ bio: { name: string; }; responses: { favoriteColor: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteFood: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteCar?: undefined; }; } | { bio: { name: string; }; responses: { ...; }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'userInfo[]'.
        Type '{ bio: { name: string; }; responses: { favoriteColor: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteFood: { answer: string; level: number; }; favoriteCar?: undefined; }; } | { bio: { name: string; }; responses: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'userInfo'.


I noticed, the error appears when I add the question "favoriteCar" for the second element! And if I have the same questions for both elements then there is no error!
What does it mean? Does it mean list of records need the same key?!

You can provide a type hint on mockUserInfo(), and then it accepts it. Without one, it deduces a specific object type for responses, rather than Record<string, Response>.
mockUserInfo(): userInformation[]

Playground link
